# How do I find the dot product of these vectors?

Tags: geometry

We know that :

- ABCD is a square.
- BGFE is a square.
- AEB is an equilateral triangle.
- AB = 1.

Here is the figure :
[image]
How can I find the scalar products of :
 • BC.BE
 • DA.BE
 • EA.EB

Comment: The scalar product of two unit vectors is simply the cosine of the angle between them. Once you label the appropriate angles in your diagram you should be good to go.

Comment: I don't understand at all :(

Comment: What can you say about $BC$ and $DE$ as vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $v$ and $w$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $v\cdot w=\|v\|\|w\|\cos{\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $w$ and $\|v\|$ and $\|w\|$ are the lengths of the vectors. So since each of your vectors has length 1, this problem reduces to finding the angles between each of these pairs of vectors.

We are given that $AEB$ is an equilateral triangle, so the angle between $EA$ and $EB$ is $60^\circ$. The sum of the angles between $AB$ and $BE$ ($60^\circ$) and $BE$ and $BC$ must sum to $90^\circ$, so the angle between $BC$ and $BE$ is $30^\circ$. Finally, to find the angle between $DA$ and $BE$, we need to translate $BE$ over to the point $D$. Then we see that the angle is $90^\circ$ plus the angle between $AB$ and $BE$ ($60^\circ$), and hence is $150^\circ$.

So $BC\cdot BE=1\cdot 1\cdot\cos{30^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $DA\cdot BE=1\cdot1\cdot\cos{150^\circ}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $EA\cdot EB=1\cdot1\cdot\cos{60^\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I just have trouble to understand how do you find the measure of the angle between DA and BE :/

Comment: Take the line $BE$ and imagine that the same line (i.e. with the same length and pointing in the same direction) starts at the point $B$ instead of $D$.